# Equation with definite integral.

Tags: definite-integrals

Suppose that I have a function $f(x,y)$,

I want to solve

$$\int_a^bf(x,y)dx =0.$$

w.r.t $y$.
Is it possible to say that this is equivalent to solve

$$f(b,y)-f(a,y) =0$$

since I can multiply on both the sides by $\frac{d}{dx}$?

Comment: I already have $f(x,y)$ and I want to find $y$ which satisfies the first equation. Since computing the integral might be impossible, I was wondering if the solution of the second equation (w.r.t $y$) is the same as the solution of the first equation.

Comment: No, differentiation is no good for this.  In general, when you solve $f(x)=0$ you get just one point, and it does not follow that $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=0$ at that one point.  That is, the point where a graph crosses the $x$-axis is not also a point where the tangent to the graph is horizontal.

Comment: I see, thanks @GEdgar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion is not correct.

**Counterexample**

Consider $f(x,y)=\cos(x+y),$ $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x+y)=\sin(\pi+y)-\sin y=-2\sin y.$$ For $y={\pi}\;$ takes the integral the value $0.$
But 
$$\cos(\pi+\pi)-\cos (0+\pi)=2\neq 0.$$

Comment: Thanks! I suspected it. But can you explain to me why is not that? If my integral was indefinite I could have done $\int f(x) dx = 0 \implies \int \frac{d}{dx}f(x) dx = \frac{d}{dx} 0 \implies f(x) +c = 0$ but usually the $c$ cancel out when I have definite integral

Comment: The result is a function of $y,$ say $G(y)=\int_a^bf(x,y)dx.$ You can derivate it or integrate, but w.r.t. $y.$  If you post a new question with your function $f(x,y)$ it is not excluded that MSE solves the integral.